# Where can I find specific Linux system libraries' source code?

Tags: linux, lib

I'm working on a product where we ship binaries with Linux system libs from our environment like `ld-2.19.so`, `libdl-2.19.so`, `libgcc_s.so.1` etc.

Now we are expected to provide the source codes of these libs (for management and software clearing reasons).

These are Linux libraries and yeah it's opensource, but the expectation is to provide az exact .tar.gz.

I have 2 questions.

1. As I investigate, some of these libraries come from GNU libc? So glibc is not only one .so file, many .so files are come from GNU libc such as libc, libpthread etc.
2. Two of the mentoined libs end with 2.19. How can I tell a .so file comes from what "package"? For example, these .so files comes from GNU libc?

Thank you

Comment: What linux are you using? See that linux package manager -> in those are all the steps needed to build the package, _including_ all source files.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu14

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/ ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the source where the file comes from. On a typical linux distribution you do:

- query the package manager from which package does the file come from
- get that package build scripts
- in that build script is the source location

Major distributions have similar sites like https://packages.ubuntu.com/ or https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages or https://archlinux.org/packages/ with sources on how to build packages. RPM packages have `-source` packages with the sources for packages.

Comment: Thanks, now I found the proper packages' full source code. I used `dpkg -S [soname]`. Now I found the complete source code of glibc. As a programmer I think a deeper understanding the source code should be needed to select only a few source files that build up a specific .so lib. It's not so simple to look for `ld-2.19.c`, probably is not build by a single C file. Can you confirm if I'm right?

Comment: Yes, many, many, many source files are used to build one shared library.